# How to use Visual Studio Code as the default MergeTool for mercurial

Tags: visual-studio-code, mercurial, mergetool

To change the default merge method, what is configuration is needed to provide the `.hgrc` file. I tried the google but it didn't work.

Comment: From what I read in this link, it sounds like VSCode only has some diff capability, not merge: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/37350

Comment: It has what they call "merge" functionality, but its quite limited - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_merge-conflicts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you wanted to use "Visual Studio Code"'s version control - [Merge Conflicts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_merge-conflicts) feature. And I guess that you wanted the same feature, but with mercurial's source control.

So, the first thing we have to do is to configure mercurial to use VSCode as the merge tool. To do it, I look at the following [documentation](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/hgrc.5.html#merge-tools).

Seems like the mercurial want to know the Registry value of VSCode for activating it.
I looked around the internet and found this [gitlab Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/37807#issuecomment-343493092) with the relevant keys.

So the current additional configuration is:

```
[merge-tools]
vscode.regkey=SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{EA457B21-F73E-494C-ACAB-524FDE069978}_is1
vscode.regname=DisplayIcon
vscode.args= --wait $output
vscode.binary=False
vscode.gui=True
vscode.checkconflicts=True
vscode.premerge=keep

[extensions]
extdiff=

[merge-patterns]
*.*=vscode

[ui]
merge= :vscode
```

BAM! Works!

### Possible problems

#### Missing line terminator

During the testing of this configuration, I encountered a problem when there is a conflict that has no line terminator (\n) at the end.

*Notice: There is no a '\n' at the end of the file*

file.txt (branch 'foo')

```
foo
```

file.txt (branch 'bar')

```
bar
```

The result of `$output` is:

file.txt (merge output)

```
<<<<<<< working copy
foo=======
bar>>>>>>> merge rev
```

and VSCode's merge conflict solver cannot detect this part of the code as a conflict because the code that detects `=======` and `>>>>>>>` assumes that they are places at the begging of the line like this:

```
<<<<<<< working copy
foo
=======
bar
>>>>>>> merge rev
```

We can see this assumption [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/2281a3f65d27a322dcd2da06cf9b3aacfc2b9289/extensions/merge-conflict/src/mergeConflictParser.ts#L61) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/2281a3f65d27a322dcd2da06cf9b3aacfc2b9289/extensions/merge-conflict/src/mergeConflictParser.ts#L65). I think it is perfectly fine, but I had to add this to avoid any future problems.

Here you have it, have fun.

Answer (score 3):

We can use vscode as merge tool by using the [vscode-hg](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrcrowl.hg) plugin. But the problem is we cannot simply configure the vscode as merge tool in the `.hgrc` file.

Set the merge tool as `: merge`  on the .hgrc file, this will allow merging the file using the vscode hg plugin.

```
[ui]
merge = :merge
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Nohow. VS Code can be used only as diff-tool, not as 3-way mergetool